# ServiceExecute for PubChem error when CID not found

Tags: chemistry, serviceexecute

I am trying to download properties of compounds from PubChem using ServiceExecute. However, I only possess names of compounds as strings. It appears that ServiceExecute exits completely even if the one of compound lookups fails and returns no output for the rest that worked out. I wonder if there is a way to change this behavior, so that I can get the data for the compounds that worked correctly. A minimal example is shown below:

```
chems = {"(+)-a-pinene", "(+)-camphene", "(-)-a-pinene", "(-)-b-citronellol", "(-)-camphene"};
```

`ServiceExecute["PubChem", "CompoundProperties", {"Name" -> chems[[2]]}]`

This works because camphene is interpreted correctly. However, if I try the entire list of names,

`ServiceExecute["PubChem", "CompoundProperties", {"Name" -> chems}]`

I get the following error message

> During evaluation of In[131]:= ServiceExecute::serrormsg: Server error. Error message: No CID found
> Server error. Error message: No CID found

Is there a way to get ServiceExecute to keep going when it encounters an error and return the properties for which the call worked?

Thanks,

Version Information: Running Mathematica v13 on Linux box (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS).

Comment: My very naive and simple solution is to map over every single compound name: ``ServiceExecute["PubChem", "CompoundProperties", {"Name" -> #}] & /@ chems``.

Comment: Yes, that is a workaround. However, I am hoping that there is a cleaner way to use ServiceExecute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another workaround:

```
$Version

(* "13.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Look for interpreter types related to chemistry

```
Select[$InterpreterTypes, 
 Length@StringCases[#, "chem", IgnoreCase -> True] > 0 &]

(* {"Chemical", "ChemicalClass", "ComputedChemical", \
"ComputedFamousChemistryProblem", "FamousChemistryProblem"} *)

chems = {"(+)-a-pinene", "(+)-camphene", "(-)-a-pinene", "(-)-b-citronellol", 
   "(-)-camphene"};
```

Select elements of `chems` that are interpreted as computed chemicals.

```
chems2 = Select[chems, 
   FreeQ[Interpreter["ComputedChemical"][#], Failure] &] //
   Quiet

(* {"(+)-camphene", "(-)-camphene"} *)
```

Then

```
ServiceExecute["PubChem", "CompoundProperties", {"Name" -> chems2}]
```

Comment: Thank you, I have accepted your answer. However, I still hope that ServiceExecute turns out to have a better error handling mechanism.